# Colorize Entire Row of Cells Having a Text/Value on a Column in Excel using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, epplus

I need to format entire row of cells having a value on a column using EPPlus.

**For example, colorize rows having text of "yes" on its 'H' column.**

In order to achieve this I used excel conditional formatting rules(EPPlus) but I could only format cells, not entire row. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show us how you formatted a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `worksheet` is an `ExcelWorksheet` and `rowNumber` is... that:

```
var rangeAddress = $"{rowNumber}:{rowNumber}";
var expression = worksheet.ConditionalFormatting
    .AddExpression(new ExcelAddress(rangeAddress));
expression.Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.00";

// not trying to be lazy here - you already have your formula.
expression.Formula = "IF(something)";
```

Comment: The confusing part is there is one address range. It is for which cells the rule will be applied on(for my case specific column, i.e. H column, of all rows). But, how can it decide to format entire row of cells the rule pass ?

Comment: When you add the expression, the first argument (range address) specifies what range get formatted. That could be a cell, a row, a bunch of cells, anything. The formula is totally separate. If that formula returns true then the style is applied to the entire range specified in the first argument.

Comment: If they are seperate, another question comes out; how can it relate the cell in the formula and range address to be formatted ? For example, if a cell in the H column is passed the rule; how does it know cells in the same row to format?

Comment: I think the answer lies in the way the conditional formatting is applied. When you call `AddExpression` you're creating a new object that contains that entire specification - a formula, a style, and a range of cells to apply the style to. Then it's adding that entire object to the workbook. Now the workbook contains one or more of these conditional formatting specifications that it can apply when the workbook changes.